# Power Query, Remove 1st 2 characters in string

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a column of telephone numbers in slightly different formats due to how the agents input them into the database. Some start with a `0` and some with `44` (country code). I have found a code online that has helped me remove the 0's at the start of the string but now I am trying to adapt this to remove the `44` at the beginning of the string and for some reason, it doesn't seem to want to play ball.

```
= Table.TransformColumns(
#"Renamed Columns",
{{
"telephone",
each if Text.Start(Text.From(_),2)="44" 
then 
""&Text.From(_) 
else _ 
}})
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"telephone",each if Text.Start(Text.From(_),2)="44" then Text.RemoveRange(Text.From(_),0,2) else _ }})
```

Comment: Works great thanks, was it simply the `,0` that was missing?